# SELECT employees with count of finished tasks

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum, pivot

How would do the following in SQL:

"select all emps with list mark all one's tasks".................................

```
EmpId  EmpName
------ --------
1        tom
2        jerry
3        jack


taskId EmpID    mark
------ -----   ------
1       1        5
2       3        0
3       1        10
4       2        5
5       2        10
6       3        5
7       3        5
```

**Result:**

```
EmpName  0       5       10    sum
------ -----   ------  ------  ----
tom      0       1        1     2
jerry    0       1        1     2
jack     1       2        0     3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.mark = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 0Mark, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.mark = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 5Mark, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.mark = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 10Mark, 
       COUNT(1) AS TotalMark
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN task t ON e.EmpId = t.EmpId 
GROUP BY e.EmpId, e.EmpName;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select
   e.empname,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark=0) as mark0,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark=5) as mark5,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark=10) as mark10,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid) as marksum        
from       
   employees e
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your database engine - google "Pivot SQL " + your database engine (e.g. "pivot SQL MySQL").

The pivot feature means that you can convert values in the "mark" column to column headers, so if you have marks ranging from 0 to 100, you get one column for each value without having to create a subquery.

If your database engine doesn't support pivot, you may need to hard-code the columns in your resultset as @LajosVeres shows. I would add a "catch-all" subquery so if your data changes, you don't get illogical results, like so:

```
select
   e.empname,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark=0) as mark0,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark=5) as mark5,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark=10) as mark10,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid and mark not in (0, 5, 10)) as otherMarks,
   (select count(*) from tasks t where e.empid=t.empid) as marksum        
from       
   employees e
```